# File directory in with r-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I need some help knitting my rMarkdown. I have used these lines of code and they are a working directory, but in Markdown I keep getting an error.
Input:

```
read.csv("~/Downloads/Datasets from Box/2022-03-08_habit-and-OCD_clinical.csv")
read.csv("~/Downloads/Datasets from Box/2022-03-07_habit-and-OCD_clinical.csv"
```

Output:

```
Error in file (file, "rt"): cannot open the connection
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., dput(head(x)) or data.frame(...)) directly. This said: Remove the `setwd()`. As you already included the full path to your datasets in `read.csv` there is no reason to switch the working directory. Also, see https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/ on why it's best to forget about `setwd`.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I didn't know that about the images, I won't post those again. I updated my post because I tried getting rid of the setwd, but still received an error code.

Comment: Try using `fc <- file.choose()` and navigate to the file location. Then compare `fc` to what you have within quotes in `read.csv()`. More than likely there is something different. You can use `all.equal(fc, readCSVobj)` to have the system tell you the difference, as well. (Both functions are in base R, so no libraries are needed.)